# How to build a web App with Git front end utils?

Tags: git

I know how to work in git. But, now I want to set up a git server in my org. so that developers can access it via internet from any where around the globe. I know about Github and I want to build my own custom git server for my organisation developers alone and I donot wish to outsource it to git hub like apps.

I need to provide browser based front end apart from console based. **My server machine have windows Operating system.** **and we use java for our webdevelopment**

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at "Web Interface" section of [InterfacesFrontendsAndTools](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#web-interface) page on Git wiki, and at [Gitweb](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/Gitweb) page, also on Git wiki.

---

Below there is (probably incomplete) list of various git web interfaces and integrated git hosting solutions:

Pure web interfaces (I guess that most commonly used are **gitweb** and **cgit**):

- gitweb ([README](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=gitweb/README;hb=HEAD)) - in Perl, part of git
- [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/) - in C
- [viewgit](http://viewgit.sourceforge.net/) - in PHP
- [GitPHP](http://www.xiphux.com/programming/php/gitphp/) - in PHP
- git-php: [1](http://code.google.com/p/git-php/), [2](http://people.proekspert.ee/peeter/git/git.php), [3](http://github.com/josegonzalez/git-php) - in PHP
- [ginatra](https://github.com/narkoz/ginatra) - in Ruby, using Sinatra framework
- [Gitalist](http://github.com/broquaint/Gitalist) and [Gitcat](http://github.com/lestrrat/Gitcat/) - in Perl, using Catalyst framework
- [django-git](http://github.com/sethtrain/django-git/) and [django-gitweb](http://github.com/stephrdev/django-gitweb) - in Python, using Django framework

Git hosting solutions (forges) with built-in web interface:

- [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline/trees/master) - in Ruby
- [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net) - in PHP
- [GitHub:FI](http://fi.github.com/) - in Ruby, proprietary

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Gitweb](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/Gitweb). Their homepage not only provides the details on Gitweb itself, but also on alternative web frontends to git.

Answer (score 0):

One option: grab the source for [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline/trees/master) and customize it for your needs.

Comment: but my server operating system is windows